# Gostaria de exibir um arquivo txt usando JS ou PHP respeitando a quebra de linha

Tags: php, javascript, aplicação-web, include, require

Eu tentei included e require, porém eles não respeitam a quebra de linha.

Quero imprimir as informações do arquivo dentro de um `<p>`, somente para estudo.

Comment: John descreva melhor de exemplos, porque a pergunta pode ser marcada como pendente

Comment: Coloque o conteúdo dentro da tag <pre></pre>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Utilizando uma solução pronta

Substituir a tag `<p>` pela tag `<pre>`, assim a página respeitará as quebras de linha, caso o texto não fique formatado como desejar, basta setar um estilo para tag `<pre>`.

```css
pre{
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<pre>
Texto com quebra de linha aqui
Texto com quebra de linha aqui
Texto com quebra de linha aqui
Texto com quebra de linha aqui
Texto com quebra de linha aqui
Texto com quebra de linha aqui
</pre>
```

## Continue usando a tag p

Você pode fazer este mesmo efeito da tag `<pre>` usando o `css`.

```css
p{
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<p>
Texto com quebra de linha aqui
Texto com quebra de linha aqui
Texto com quebra de linha aqui
Texto com quebra de linha aqui
Texto com quebra de linha aqui
Texto com quebra de linha aqui
</p>
```

Basta seta a seguinte regra ao seu estilo css

```
white-space: pre;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, foi uma solução bem simples, achei que precisava adicionar mais alguns comando no php, mas só a tag resolveu.

`<pre style="color: red; font-size: 16px;">
  <?php
   include 'text.txt';
  ?>
 </pre>`